# Goroutine of listen and serve blocks execution of main process, never reaches following select state used for communication

Tags: go, concurrency, websocket, server, goroutine

Still fully getting my head around goroutines and channels, so I might be doing something obviously wrong. I have a service that runs a websocket server and public route used to upgrade clients from https to wss. I am trying to attach some tear-down code for one of the routines, but the second `go` call seems to block the main function's execution. I reach Println 5 on the console on boot up. The rest of my program is happily working. I just can't kill it with a ctrl+C (nor does it do it's required tear down after a manual shut down).

Here's the relevant code (the complete main file minus the streamAddr var and the imports):

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(1)
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(0)

    fmt.Println(2)
    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    fmt.Println(3)
    hub := socktools.NewHub()
    go hub.Run()

    fmt.Println(4)
    http.HandleFunc("/stream", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        socktools.ServeWs(hub, w, r)
    })

    fmt.Println(5)
    go log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*streamAddr, nil))

    fmt.Println(6)

    select {
    case <-interrupt:
        fmt.Println("Interrupt heard...")
        close(hub.KillChan)
        <-hub.KilledChan
        fmt.Println("Ending main function")
        return
   }
}
```

Why is `go log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*streamAddr, nil))` blocking? I thought that the go keyword instantly made it asynchronous? Am I using it wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially calling `go log.Fatal(variable)`, so the async call is `log.Fatal`, but it has to know what `variable` is *at that moment*, so it first has to call `http.ListenAndServe` to see what it returns.  But `http.ListenAndServe` blocks.

You need to do:

```
go func() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*streamAddr, nil))
}()
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was some oversight like that.